# Label multiplying on file inputs

Tags: forms, symfony, twig, label, symfony4

I'm having a strange issue with my form.

If I have multiple labels on my file inputs like this :
[image]

I'm building my form dynamically from db [like this](https://pastebin.com/f28YvpLc)
and displayed in my view like this :

```
        {% for field in form.travelerinformations %}
            {{ form_row(field) }}
        {% endfor %}
```

If I have only one file input, I have no issue, if I have 2, I have 2 labels, 3 inputs, 3 labels...

I'm using bootstrap_4_horizontal_layout.html.twig form theme

Comment: I am sorry, but what exactly is your question?

Comment: how can I only have 1 label per input as it should be instead of x labels per input if I have x file inputs.

Comment: Share your FormType class